# Carry forward current value from ddl to another .aspx page

Tags: asp.net

I want to get the current selected content from the dropdown list to the next `aspx` page.

Comment: this is a very basic question, i think you are still in the learning phase. I suggest you to have a good look on the topic "working with query stings" in asp.net and you will get a good answer from  it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be helpful. 
This video shows how to pass value from textbox to next page you can replace the textbox to Drop Down list and it should work.

[Click to see video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3kbG0pYwmf8)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with :

- query string
- form submit redirection
- server.transfer
- cookie
- session

But you did not supply any code or other info which can affect the answers.